# configure: error: unrecognized option: -–with-mail=/usr/bin/sendmail while installing nagios 3.5.0

Tags: software-installation, nagios3

Following [this installation guide](http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/Installing_Nagios_Core_From_Source.pdf) when reach to the step:

```
./configure --with-nagios-group=nagios --with-command-group=nagcmd -–with-mail=/usr/bin/sendmail
```

I got the following error:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: -–with-mail=/usr/bin/sendmail 
Try `./configure --help' for more information.
```

Any idea why? Is save remove that last parameter (-–with-mail=/usr/bin/sendmail) and move on?

I did that for test and configure stage pass without error, but I'm afraid of the implication and certainly after days in production I don't want to have recompile nagios again ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, my bad! One of the "-" characters before the "with-mail" wasn't a "-". Copy paste from PDF to console not worked well this time. Sorry and thanks for your reading.